# eevee ambient occlusion animation flickering

Tags: eevee-render-engine, ambient-occlusion

when i render my animation the shadows produces by the ambient occlusion are not consistent throughout the frames causing a flicker effect. How can i fix this ?

The animation is a zoom out shot where the camera gets farther away from the text. the ambient occlusion between the text and the floor is the one that flickers. I have tried messing with shadow settings and with the ambient occlusion settings and nothing helped.